# Configure a Logitech corded mouse's special buttons to work when connected to KVM switch

Tags: macos, mouse, osx-mavericks, kvm, logitech

Here is the equipment I'm using:
- Logitech M500 corded mouse
- ioGear 2-port (DVI + USB) KVM switch
- Macbook Pro w/ OSX Mavericks

Problem:
When I try to configure the M500's special buttons (mouse wheel button, back/forward buttons) to work with OSX Mavericks via Logitech Control Center (LCC), I get an error message "No Logitech Device Found."

I contacted Logitech and they said that LCC is not compatible with KVM switches.

Any alternatives?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) and it seems to work great.

Although I don't get the device to show up in the listing of devices controlled by USB Overdrive (as the Apple keyboard does), the button assignments are, so far, working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Your KVM switch is based on Keyboard / mouse emulation technology which having problems with many wireless keyboard and mouse.  Please google DVI DDM KVM switches which are based on Dynamic Device Mapping technology and work with all different HID devices.

Comment: Interesting. Although, I'm using a wired mouse and keyboard. The Apple USB keyboard is detected just fine, while the Logitech mouse is not.